# Nim - constructors and passing objects around

Tags: class, object, reference, nim-lang

OK, the question may be a (very)beginner one, but I'm still learning.

I have two different "ref objects"

**From the "value" module:**

```
type
    Value* = ref object
        case kind*: ValueKind:
            of stringValue:
                s*: string
            of integerValue:
                i*: int
            of realValue:
                r*: float
            of booleanValue:
                b*: bool 
            of arrayValue:
                a*: seq[Value]
            of dictionaryValue:
                d*: Table[string,Value]
            of functionValue:
                f*: Function
            of objectValue:
                o*: Object

proc valueFromString*(v: string): Value =
    new(result)
    result.kind = stringValue
    result.s = v
```

From the "argument" module:

```
type
    Argument* = ref object
        case kind*: ArgumentKind:
            of identifierArgument:
                i*: int
            of literalArgument:
                v*: Value

proc argumentFromStringLiteral(l: cstring):Argument {.exportc.} =
    let ret = Argument(kind: literalArgument, v: valueFromString($l))
    return ret
```

---

The thing is the compiler complains at the penultimate line (when trying to create a new Argument):

```
type mismatch: got <Value> but expected 'Value = ref Value:ObjectType
```

What am I doing wrong? The `valueFromString` is return a "pointer" to Value object, isn't it?

Comment: Can you expand your questions so it contains a small complete example of your failing code? Because if I add the missing imports and `*Kind` enums, it compiles using nim v1.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

I'd leave this as a comment, but i don't have the reputation...

I think there's a typo in your question....that fixed your code

To get that error message, Argument would have to have been defined as

```
type
    Argument* = ref object
        case kind*: ArgumentKind:
            of identifierArgument:
                i*: int
            of literalArgument:
                v*: ref Value
```

note the 'ref Value'

the way you have it in the question compiles.